# How to get thread stack information on Windows?

Tags: windows, stack, windbg

I enumerate all threads in a process through the `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` function. I would like to get some basic stack information for each thread. More specifically I would like to get stack bottom address and if possible I would like to get current stack top address. Basically this is the information displayed with the `~*k` command in WinDbg. So how can I obtain the stack information from the thread's ID or HANDLE?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Definitions can be found [here](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/).)

To get stack boundaries:

```
THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION basicInfo;
NT_TIB tib;

// Get TEB address
NtQueryInformationThread(YOUR_THREAD_HANDLE, ThreadBasicInformation, &basicInfo, sizeof(THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION), NULL);
// Read TIB
NtReadVirtualMemory(YOUR_PROCESS_HANDLE, basicInfo.TebBaseAddress, &tib, sizeof(NT_TIB), NULL);
// Check tib.StackBase and tib.StackLimit
```

To get the value of `esp`, simply use `GetThreadContext`.

Comment: Thanks wj32! I will have a look at the link you provided.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way without having to involve the Windows Driver Kit is as so:

```
NT_TIB* tib = (NT_TIB*)__readfsdword(0x18);
size_t* stackBottom = (size_t*)tib->StackLimit;
size_t* stackTop = (size_t*)tib->StackBase;
```

Answer (score 1):

__readfsdword() works only for the current thread. So, the variant with NtQueryInformationThread() is more flexible.

Added some declarations which are missed in ntdll.h:

```
typedef enum _THREADINFOCLASS {
    ThreadBasicInformation = 0,
} THREADINFOCLASS;

typedef LONG KPRIORITY;

typedef struct _CLIENT_ID {
    HANDLE UniqueProcess;
    HANDLE UniqueThread;
} CLIENT_ID;
typedef CLIENT_ID *PCLIENT_ID;

typedef struct _THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION
{
  NTSTATUS                ExitStatus;
  PVOID                   TebBaseAddress;
  CLIENT_ID               ClientId;
  KAFFINITY               AffinityMask;
  KPRIORITY               Priority;
  KPRIORITY               BasePriority;
} THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION, *PTHREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION;
```

Answer (score 0):

As fas as I know, Toolhelp works by making a copy of basic information on heaps, modules, processes and threads. This does not include the TEB block that contains the stack bottom address. I think you need to use another API, the debugger engine API, which offers [functions to examine the stacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff543082%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way for the **current thread** (portable Win32 x86/x64 version):

```
#include <intrin.h>

NT_TIB* getTIB() {
#ifdef _M_IX86
  return (NT_TIB*)__readfsdword(0x18);
#elif _M_AMD64
  return (NT_TIB*)__readgsqword(0x30);
#else
#error unsupported architecture
#endif
}

  NT_TIB* tib = getTIB();
  void* stackBase = tib->StackBase;
  void* stackLimit = tib->StackLimit;
```

Note: `stackLimit` < `stackBase` (as stack grows downwards).

For more details refer to [Win32 TIB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block).