# How can I see the stack in Visual Studio's JIT debugger?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, stack

I am currently debugging an application with Visual Studio 2013 and I would like to see the stack after the crash, just like OllyDbg allows you to see it (in its own 'stack' box).

I **don't want** the call stack, as that only shows me calls. I'd like to see the **raw stack**, as in seeing the values pushed into it, return addresses, everything, like this:

[image: raw stack]

Is it possible?

Comment: The closest thing is here: ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918375/how-to-get-thread-stack-information-on-windows ) - have a function in your code that gets `tib.StackBase` then access that location in the "Memory" window.

Comment: I have submitted a UserVoice request for this feature: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/7166334-add-a-raw-stack-view-to-native-debugging-a-la-oll which you're free to upvote accordingly.