# Can I ask a running thread about how much stack it has been using?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, stack-overflow, stack-size

So let's say I have created a thread, on Windows OS, for which I know that the default stack size is much more than what is needed. Can I then run the application and ask the thread about the amount of stack it actually has used so that I know how much I should set its stack size instead of the default stack size?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Address space is not a scarce resource on modern operating systems and you run the risk of catastrophe if you happen to need more space.

Comment: @David is right, you don't need to worry about this.  No matter how much stack space is  potentially _available_ to a thread, _physical_ memory is only allocated as and when the thread comes to use it.  And if that's never, then that's fine.  As he says, the only resource your thread is using up until then is address space and there's plenty of that to go round, especially if your program is 64 bit.

Comment: Some applications can not (or at least not easily) be updated to 64 bit - e.g. (non-)availability of ancient third-party libraries can be a problem. And in a 32 bit application, 1 MB stack frames can quickly add up to an inconvenient amount.

Comment: @PaulGroke I don't completely disagree with that, actually.  My app is 32 bit and I do limit the size of my stacks.  You might like to repost the comment you made to remy's now deleted answer.  I was wrong, it is potentially useful to the OP. [ edit ] just seen your answer, looks good.

Comment: Note that stack requirements can change as the OS evolves. A function that previously consumed 12KB of stack might consume 20KB of stack after an OS update. Setting your stack to the minimum for a particular OS version just opens the risk that a future OS version will need more.

Comment: Good point @RaymondChen, using the bare minimum is risky. Personally I'd probably use something like double the measured size or 64kB, whichever is larger. Of course that's still risky. But depending on what your application is doing, using the linker's default of 1 MB may also be risky. I don't think there is a universal good solution for modern-ish 32 bit applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows usually doesn't *commit* the entire stack, it only *reserves* it. (Well, unless you ask it to, e.g. by specifying a non-zero stack size argument for `CreateThread` without also passing the `STACK_SIZE_PARAM_IS_A_RESERVATION` flag).

You can use this to figure out how much stack your thread has ever needed while running, including any CRT, WinAPI or third-party library calls.

To do that, simply read the `StackBase` and `StackLimit` values from the TEB - see answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918375/how-to-get-thread-stack-information-on-windows) for how to do that. The difference of the two values should be the amount of stack memory that has been *committed*, i.e. - the amount of stack memory that the thread has actually *used*.

Alternatively, if a manual process is sufficient: Simply start the application in WinDBG, set a breakpoint before the thread exits and then dump the TEB with the `!teb` command. You can also dump the entire memory map with `!address` and look for committed areas with usage `Stack`.

Comment: That's very interesting, I might just try that out for myself.